# Letters after a number, such as 1st

Tags: terminology, orthography, suffixes

Is there a name for letters that follow a number, such as the "st" in 1st or "nd" in 2nd?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_numbers_%28linguistics%29) article calls them "ordinal numbers", whereas the "cardinal numbers" are 1, 2, 3, etc. It goes on to say that they're expressed in English with "letter suffixes". The [article on ordinal indicators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator) simply calls them suffixes also.

However, the article on [English numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_numerals#Ordinal_numbers) calls them "ordinal units", though it also goes on to say that any number with the last digit of 2 will have the suffix "nd", such as twelvend, so I'm not sure if that lends credibility to that section.

Good question. I love the chance to look something up and learn a bit myself. My takeaway is that I'd just call them suffixes.

Comment: thank you! clicking around eventually got me to [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator) which says they are called "Ordinal Indicators", but letter suffixes are sufficient as well.

Comment: I think the *full* answer must be that they're **ordinal suffixes**, which in context may be shortened to just **suffixes**.