# Use of degree symbol for Latinate ordinal number shorthand

Tags: history, abbreviations, numbers, ordinal-numbers

I remember often having professors in college use **degree symbols** to write shorthand versions of **Latinate ordinal numbers**.

For example:

```
1°    Primary
2°    Secondary
3°    Tertiary
4°    Quaternary
```

I have a few questions regarding this shorthand approach:

1. **Does this approach have a name?**
2. **What is the origin of this approach?**
3. **Is it simply a shorthand developed by professors or is it
   more widely used?**

I thought I'd gain insight by exploring the use of superscript [primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_(symbol)) in the sciences, but I didn't find answers to my questions via that rabbit hole adventure...

Comment: Maybe the o up there is actually part of the word represented.  1° is "primo", 2° is "secundo", etc.

Comment: Something along the lines perhaps of the old-fashioned paper sizing: 4vo quarto, 8vo octavo, &c.?

Comment: Possible duplicates -- and a bit wider in scope, giving the correct answer not just for the degree symbol but all the ordinal indicators such as "st", "nd", and th": https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35310, https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192804

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an **ordinal indicator**.

> In written languages, an ordinal indicator is a character, or group of characters, following a numeral denoting that it is an ordinal number, rather than a cardinal number.
>
> In English orthography, this corresponds to the suffixes -st, -nd, -rd, -th in written ordinals (represented either on the line 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th or as superscript, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th)... [and] ... different characters from the superscript lower-case letter o or a, the degree symbol (°), or the ring diacritic (˚).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator)

Wikipedia further states. regarding origin :

> The practice of indicating ordinals with superscript suffixes may originate with the practice of writing a superscript o to indicate a Latin ablative in pre-modern scribal practice.

The word 'ordinal' distinguishes it from the usual way of writing numbers which is 'cardinal'.

> **Cardinal** number  n. (Arith.): a number which answers the question ‘how many?’; one of the primitive or ‘natural’ numbers

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/27862?rskey=Nx8TbC&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> **Ordinal** Marking position in an order or series; applied to those numbers which refer something to a certain place in a series

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/132351?rskey=WmJ7cO&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid)

Comment: I wasn't actually expecting such a simple or straightforward answer given how little turned up with a Google search. This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks, Nigel!

Answer (score -1):

You see it more in Spanish speaking countries. Their masculine (and pseudo-neutral) ordinal expressions all end in "o". For example: primero, segundo, tercero, cuarto etc... Conveniently abbreviated "1°,2°,3°,4°...etc." Note that it would end in "a" if the counting suffix is conjugated to the feminine form. Perhaps that is the origin. A suggestive name for the approach might be 'Spanish ordinal numbers'. At any rate, it looks like that is a searchable term.

Comment: Spanish or Italian. —And in French most ordinals are abbreviated with superscript *e*, from the suffix *–ième*.